# How to set the sdk.dir and ndk.dir paths globally

Tags: android, react-native, macos, android-ndk, android-sdk-2.3

I am facing difficulties setting the `sdk.dir` and `ndk.dir` paths on my MacBook M2 Pro for my React Native project. I have tried several workarounds, but none of them seem to be working.

My current setup includes:

- Node v14.13.0
- NPM v6.14.8
- React-Native v0.63.3.

For a temporary fix, I have been adding the following two lines to my local.properties file:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/REDACTED/Library/Android/sdk
ndk.dir=/Users/REDACTED/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462
```

If the `ndk.dir` is not properly set, I get an error message that reads "No version of NDK matched the requested version 21.0.6113669. Versions available locally: 21.1.6352462, 21.4.7075529." This is because the required NDK does not exist in my Android Studio, so I have to hardcode it inside the local.properties file.

If the `sdk.dir` is not properly set, I get an error message that reads "SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/REDACTED_PROJECT_NAME/android/local.properties'."

Here's my `.zshrc` file
[image: zshrc for reference]

Based on my current setup and requirements, I am hoping to set the `ndk.dir` and `sdk.dir` paths globally to avoid having to modify the local.properties file every time I switch to another branch. I would like these paths to be set globally and automatically detected by my React Native project.